# onclick redirection and lazy load

Tags: javascript, onclick, lazy-loading, primefaces-mobile

I want to run a javascript function when I click on a commandButton on **signin.xhtml**, but when I click on it, a redirection occur to **dev.xhtml**. I don't want this redirection, I want to stay on **signin.xhtml**. Actually it's not really a redirection because it's the same **index.xhtml** page but with lazy loading.

Here my commandButton from **signin.xhtml** :

```
<h:form id="formSignInPartner" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p:commandButton value="Géolocaliser mon commerce" onclick="getLocation()"/> 
</h:form>
```

And **index.xhtml** :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:pm="http://primefaces.org/mobile"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
     <f:view renderKitId="PRIMEFACES_MOBILE" />
     <h:head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/geolocalisationPartner.js"></script>
     </h:head>
     <h:body>
        <pm:page id="dev" lazy ="false">
            <ui:include src="trash/dev.xhtml"/>
        </pm:page>
        <pm:page id="partnerSignIn" lazy="true">
            <ui:include src="/Partner/signIn.xhtml"/>
        </pm:page>
      </h:body>
    </html>
```

Here the script **geolocalisationPartner.js** but I don't think It's the problem

```
var options = {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout: 5000,
    maximumAge: 0
};
function error(msg) {
    alert('Geolocalisation échouée :\n' + msg);
}
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, error, options);
    } else {
        alert('Votre navigateur\nne supporte pas\nla geolocalisation');
     }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    var long = position.coords.longitude;
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('partnerSignIn:formSignInPartner:idlongitude')).val(long);
    $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('partnerSignIn:formSignInPartner:idlatitude')).val(lat);
    alert('Geolocalisation réussie !');

}
```

Comment: I found the problem. In the javascrip console,I saw my script file was not found. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. In the javascrip console,I saw my script file was not found, the path was erroneous.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event.preventDefault`

**script**

```
function getLocation(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    // your code here
}
```

**xhtml**

```
<p:commandButton value="Géolocaliser mon commerce" onclick="getLocation(e)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [cancel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) the event if you don't want it to link.

```
function getLocation(evt) {
     evt.preventDefault();
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, error, options);
    } else {
        alert('Votre navigateur\nne supporte pas\nla geolocalisation');
     }
}
```

Update your html:

```
<p:commandButton value="Géolocaliser mon commerce" onclick="getLocation(evt)"/>
```

Comment: Thank you but It's not working. It's even worst, before adding the prevent default, I could reach the signin.xhtml again and then the commandButton did not redirect me (the url change from http://localhost:8080/Zelda-web  to http://localhost:8080/Zelda-web/faces/index.xhtml after the first click) but now it redirect me everytime